# Is there a way to delimit "ucwords()" in PHP such that the first char is not automatically uppercased?

Tags: php

PHP has the function `ucwords()`, which allows for custom delimiters. This works well, and will turn `my test string` into `My Test String` no problem.

Take the following example: I want to make a super awesome 2009 gamer tag.

```
$gamerTag = 'xxx_l33t_xxx'; // Not yet epic. 
echo ucwords($gamerTag,"x"); // want it to return 'xXx_l33t_xXx'
```

I would have assumed strings would delimit case-sensitively and update the the second `x` in each case, ignoring the third, since at that point the middle one would no longer match our delimiter.

However, this actually returns `XxX_l33t_xXx`, since it will automatically uppercase the first letter in the string.

I know that there are other methods of doing this (`strsplit()` array loops and pregreplace with a reverse lookup come to mind), but my primary question becomes the following:

Is there a way to delimit `ucwords()` such that it does not automatically uppercase the first character of the string?

Comment: Sorry but the question is quite meaningless ...the function name is ucwords(), and is defined as: Uppercase the first character of each word in a string. Why it shouldn't do what it is just meant to do?

Comment: I think you don't know the point of these functions... why not use regex and positioning to determine your capitals?

Comment: I agree that a different method would be more effective, but for this specific case you could add a character to the beginning and strip it off later, like `ltrim(ucwords('!'.$gamerTag,'x'),'!')`.

Comment: @zioMitch Because the docs define a "word" as *any string of characters that is immediately after any character listed in the delimiters parameter*, and the delimiter given here is **x**. It's a valid question.

Comment: First character will always be uppercased. You can only deal with delimiters to change splitting of strings to make sure that the char you want to uppercase comes out as the first character of the splitted strings, but your requirement doesn't seem to be possible here with just `ucwords()`

Comment: I've just found an open PHP bug for a documentation fix [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78393), so you're not the only one who's noticed.

Comment: @zioMitch the point of this is trying to understand the extent of delimiters as it is expected to interact with the string.

Comment: @treyBake I understand the intended use. I know there are other tools. I just want to better understand the delimiters and am using an example string (I am not trying to make a gamer tag generator).

Comment: @iainn ok the point is that he is defining x as delimiter in is tokenizer. So the be coherent with doc usage, by consturction he is wrongly using the delimter that need at least to be escaped in its second and fourth usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal behaviour is unfortunately that the first character of the string will **always** be converted to upper case, regardless of the delimiters you pass in.

Digging into the PHP source, this is the implementation of `ucwords`:

```
*r = toupper((unsigned char) *r);

for (r_end = r + Z_STRLEN_P(return_value) - 1; r < r_end; ) {
    if (mask[(unsigned char)*r++]) {
        *r = toupper((unsigned char) *r);
    }
}
```

From https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L2651

Here `r` is the return value, and `mask` is a char array of the delimiting characters. The first call to `toupper` (outside the of the loop) means that there's no way to prevent the first character being converted.

Because this is done, it means the second character is not converted, since it's now preceded by **X**, not **x**. The *third* character is handled "correctly".

This can actually cause some strange cascading behaviour, since the return value is being iterated over while it's being modified:

```
php > echo ucwords('aaa', 'A');
AAA
```

The initial string doesn't contain the delimiting character anywhere, but the result is completely upper-case.

As mentioned in a comment, there's an open PHP bug to reflect this behaviour in the documentation here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78393